# How do I set my application as default for a file type in Windows 8.1 without an additional prompt?

Tags: windows, registry

My company has a Windows application that users may want to set as the default to open a particular file type. We have a button within our application that users can click to do this; this was automatic in Windows 7, but in Windows 8, the best we can do is to open a window listing registered handlers for that file type.
Other applications, in particular Adobe Reader, seem to have found a way to immediately set themselves as the default program (for PDFs, in their case) without showing this window, but we have not been able to figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: found this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1801781 . not so bad workaround

Comment: I'd rather not delete other file handlers out of users' registries if necessary, and Adobe doesn't seem to be doing it this way. I'll keep this in mind, though, thank you.

Comment: How are you currently trying to do it that isn't working?

Comment: I wish I could answer that, but I'm a PM, not a developer, and I don't know the exact method we use. Whatever it is we currently do brings up a "How do you want to open this type of file?" window. It seems that this is what Microsoft wants us to do, but it's really just an extra step, considering we're only doing this after a user specifically clicks a button to make us the default...